# JavaFX: WindowEvent.WINDOW_HIDDEN

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, eventhandler

I have written my own EventHandler, which does not do somethin special. It is just for practicing. Here he comes:

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

public class JavaFXMyWindowListener implements EventHandler<WindowEvent>{

    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {

        System.out.println("WindowEvent: " +  event.getEventType());

        if(event.getEventType() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST){
            System.out.println("Window closed");
            event.consume();
        }

        if(event.getEventType() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWING){
            System.out.println("Window activ");
        }

        if(event.getEventType() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN){
            System.out.println("Window opened");
        }

        if(event.getEventType() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_HIDDEN){
            System.out.println("Window minimized");
        }

        if(event.getEventType() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_HIDING){
            System.out.println("Window is going to be minimized");
        }

    }

}
```

I have problems with the last du if. WINDOW_HIDDEN & WINDOW_HIDING dont seem to work, because that System.out never happens when i minimize the window. The other 3 Events work. Also the top most System.out doesnt occur, that means the event never happens. I have added the eventhandler as follow in the mainclass:

```
stage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.ANY, new JavaFXMyWindowListener());
```

I have found the following workaround:

```
stage.iconifiedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
      @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> prop, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
          if(newValue){
              System.out.println("Window minimized");
          }else{
              System.out.println("Window was minimized and gets back now");
          }
      }
});
```

It is doing what i wanted to do, but why doesnt WINDOW_HIDDEN & WINDOW_HIDING Working? i dont understand, please help. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

`HIDING` and `HIDDEN` means "closing" and "closed", respectively, not minimized (it refers to the `hide()` method).

For a `Stage`, you can register a listener with the [`iconified` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#iconifiedProperty) to respond when it is minimized.